# Get Data Problem with Foreignkey Models QuerySet (Django)

Tags: django

I am making django practising. I found a repo and edited to myself. When i came to the get data from models with foreignkey, i get query instead of data. I think my function is a little bit spagetti or my template file.
Full repo is here https://github.com/eseymenler/demo2

Here is the output of my codes. First red square is query, but i want second red square datas.

Hasta Adı:  {{ patient.name }}
Hastanın Sağlık Problemi:  {{ prob }}
Hastanın Boyu:  {{ vital }}
Hastanın Sigara Kullanım Durumu:  {{ social }}

First data {{ patient.name }} is very good for me. Thats what i want.
But when i get write {{ prob.problem }} it gives me nothing. So where is my fault.
But also when i make for loop like this, i get data which i want. So how can i fix this.

```
{% for y in prob %}
        {{ y.problem }}
{% endfor %}
```

[image]

And my views.py

```
@login_required()
def patienttumbilgiListView(request, id):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(aadhaarId = id)
    prob = ProblemList.objects.filter(patient = patient)
    vital = VitalSign.objects.filter(patient = patient) 
    social = SocialHistory.objects.filter(patient = patient)


    return render(
        request, 'patient_records/patient-problem-tum.html',
        context={'prob': prob, 'vital': vital, 'social': social, 'patient': patient })
```

and my template file

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}problem-list-view{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
Hasta Adı:  {{ patient.name }}</br>
Hastanın Sağlık Problemi:  {{ prob }}<br>
Hastanın Boyu:  {{ vital }}<br>
Hastanın Sigara Kullanım Durumu:  {{ social }} <br></div>
<br>
<br>





<div class="container">

<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{border-color:black;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;
font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="tg-0lax">Hasta Adı:</th>
<th class="tg-0lax">{{ patient.name }}</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="tg-0lax">Hastanın Sağlık Problemi:</td>
<td class="tg-0lax">{% for y in prob %}<br>    <br>        {{ y.problem }}<br>                            <br>    <br>{% endfor %}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-0lax">Hastanın Boyu:</td>
<td class="tg-0lax">{% for x in vital %}<br>    <br>        {{ x.height }}<br>                            <br>    <br>{% endfor %}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-0lax">Sigara Kullanımı:</td>
<td class="tg-0lax">{% for item in social %}<br>    <br><br>        {{ item.tobacco_smoking_status }}<br>                            <br>   <br>{% endfor %}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
<br>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Based on your code, I think that patient is unique. So you really don't need a loop in a template, and you should just be able to reformat what context variables you send to your template in your view to be the value from the 1 object returned by your query set instead of your queryset. What does that look like? `# your queries here; prob = prob[0] if len(prob) == 1 else None; vital = vital[0] if len(vital) == 1 else None; social = social[0] if len(social) == 1 else None;` then in your template, get the variables like you would with getting attributes with the `.` syntax. I have to leave. BRB.

Comment: @Shmack i add your answer to my function on views.py and then i changed {{ prob.problem }} but nothing changed. 
i add these code to my actual function code. is this right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Roughly What You Had

So your code is:

```
@login_required()
def patienttumbilgiListView(request, id):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(aadhaarId = id)
    prob = ProblemList.objects.filter(patient = patient)
    vital = VitalSign.objects.filter(patient = patient) 
    social = SocialHistory.objects.filter(patient = patient)


    return render(
        request, 'patient_records/patient-problem-tum.html',
        context={'prob': prob, 'vital': vital, 'social': social, 'patient': patient })
```

```
{% for y in prob %}
    {{y.problem}}
{% endfor %}

{% for x in vital %}
    {{x.height}}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in social %}
    {{item.tobacco_smoking_status}}
{% endfor %}
```

## Some Friendly Suggestions

**"id" is a reserved word / function** - I suggest changing `id` to maybe `pid` in your code.

**Return an error to your view** - You don't necessarily have to make this change, but I think its a good idea, and can even help with troubleshooting. I mean you should probably be returning an error or something to this chart if you can't find these objects with those `id`s in your database.

**"get()" throws a DoesNotExist error if the id isn't found** - You should catch the error and return it to the console you are making or do something like that.

### views.py

```
@login_required()
def patienttumbilgiListView(request, pid):
    context = {}
    try:
        patient = Patient.objects.get(aadhaarId = pid)
    except DoesNotExist:
        context['error'] = f"Could not find patient with id '{pid}'."
    else:
        context['prob'] = ProblemList.objects.filter(patient=patient)
        context['vital'] = VitalSign.objects.filter(patient=patient) 
        context['social'] = SocialHistory.objects.filter(patient=patient)
        context['patient'] = patient

    return render(request, 'patient_records/patient-problem-tum.html', context=context)
```

### template.html

```
{% if error %}
    {{error}}
{% endif %}

{% for y in prob %}
    {{y.problem}}
{% empty %}
    Could not find problems.
{% endfor %}

{% for x in vital %}
    {{x.height}}
{% empty %}
    Could not find vitals.
{% endfor %}

{% for item in social %}
    {{item.tobacco_smoking_status}}
{% empty %}
    Could not find socials.
{% endfor %}
```

## What Your Problem Is And How To Solve It

> I am making django practising. I found a repo and edited to myself. When i came to the get data from models with foreignkey, i get query instead of data.

Based on this quote, I am assuming you want to know why the data is being returned as a queryset instead of as a singular result. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

> filter() will always give you a QuerySet, even if only a single object matches the query - in this case, it will be a QuerySet containing a single element. If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the get() method on a Manager which returns the object directly: `one_entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)`.

Which is why you should use the for loop in your template.html. If you don't want to  use that, then you should preprocess this data either by using `get()` instead of `filter()` or simply, in the context, send the `[0]` element to the template from your view.

So, to clarify, if you want to use `{{prob.problem}}` in your template, you need to change your view to either do `prob = ProblemList.objects.filter(patient = patient)[0]` or `prob = ProblemList.objects.get(patient = patient)`. If you choose the first, you should check the length (`prob = prob[0] if len(prob) == 1 else None`), otherwise, if you choose the latter, you should wrap it with a `try, except, else` clause like this:

```
try:
    prob = ProblemList.objects.get(patient=patient)
except DoesNotExist:
    context['error'] = "Could not find ProblemList."
    print("Does Not Exist")
else:
    context['prob'] = prob
```

or you could just use the for loop that you have in place, I don't know how many entries you are expecting the query set to have per patient.

If I need to further clarify anything, please let me know.

Comment: Thank u @shmack, using get solve my problem and in addition i understood where i use get and where i use filter. Also extra informations are pireceless. Thanks you very much.